# Seismic amplitude distribution

Tags: seismic, statistics

Recorded (or *raw*) and processed pre/post-stack seismic data (relative amplitudes) usually display a standard normal distribution, albeit with a very small amount of skewness.

What would be possible causes and/or significance if amplitudes did not retain a mean value of zero (or very nearly zero)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are several possible reasons.

I'm not a seismologist, this is an amateur answer only.

### Tidal forces

Local acceleration has very small long-term drifts due to tidal forces from the Sun and the Moon. These will have periods of roughly 1 day as the Earth rotates. Most seismometer data will have been run through a high-pass filter with a much higher cutoff frequency than this (of course along with other filtering). This might be implemented with some baseline restoring function other than a simple filter.

### Real changes in local *g* due to displacement in the Earth

Prompt gravity signals -- changes in local *g* as mass distribution in the Earth changes -- have been detected, and this kind of measurement may become more widely used in the future. Of course a typical seismometer will not be sensitive to pick this up, unless of course your seismometer is sitting atop a substantial geological event!

See:

- [Prompt gravity signal induced by the 2011 Tohoku-Oki earthquake - could this really be useful for warnings?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/9192/6031)
- [Earthquake-induced prompt gravity signals identified in dense array data in Japan](https://earth-planets-space.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40623-019-1006-x)
- [Gravity sensors might offer earlier warning of earthquakes](https://phys.org/news/2016-11-gravity-sensors-earlier-earthquakes.html)

### Instrumental effects

- Drift due to thermal changes
- Tilt due to geological changes (the z accelerometer is no longer pointing in the same direction)
- Tilt due to improperly mounted seismometer that was shaken loose by the earthquake
- others...